# MQTT and CoAP Sensors and Actuators

Tags: mqtt, iot, coap

MQTT and CoAP are being promoted as standard protocols that allow connecting constrained devices to the Internet.

I'm interested in a list of sensors and actuators that support these two protocols either in a native way or through a mesh/gateway.

Comment: Are you looking for sensor with a specific function or a device platform?

Comment: I'm interested in a list, as wide as possible. I'm defining my directions within IoT and one of the question I need an answer for is the protocol to use to connect sensors and actuators. ZigBee and Z-Wave are widely used but they are closed protocols. MQTT and CoAP, being open protocols, are more interesting from my point of view.

Answer (score 4):

For CoAP:
Every 6LowPAN sensor mote have a CoAP client,
for example the one running contiki: http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html
or OpenWSN, RIOTOS

Also you can use any Arduino: https://github.com/1248/microcoap

Answer (score 4):

One that is worth checking in addition to Julien's List is mBed from ARM

https://mbed.org/

it supports both CoAP and MQTT

Answer (score 0):

CoAP/MQTT and sensors/actuators are two different entities. You can implement any sensors or resources with CoAP and MQTT.

CoAP and MQTT are application layer protocol that uses TCP/UDP to transfer data (for example, sensor readings) over network.
For example in CoAP, all sensors on your hardware are treated as 'resource'. CoAP provides GET, PUT, POST, DELETE interface to manipulate with resource.
It is developers responsibility to attach its custom handlers to above interface. For example, attach read_temperature_sensor_data() to 'GET' interface, attach set_clock_time() to 'PUT' interface etc.

Comment: Thank you @electrospark.

Comment: Thank you @electrospark.
Yes, indeed, they are two different entities and my question was about objects that are sensors or actuators and can use 'of-the-shelf' CoAP or MQTT protocols.
In other words: is there any offer in the market that let you get a sensor that can send its reading using one of the two protocols?